# Role {687992085416116235, 687622939985838080} is required to run this command. [discord.py + python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Написал админ команды и задал @commands.has_role(config.ADMIN_ROLES). Есть ли у меня или нет роли - не имеет значения, всё время ошибка. Как можно исправить?

````
# Ошибка
Role {687992085416116235, 687622939985838080} is required to run this  command. 

# Роли, заданные в конфиге
ADMIN_ROLES = { 
      687992085416116235, 
      687622939985838080,
}

# Код команды
@client.command(pass_context = True) 
@commands.has_role(config.ADMIN_ROLES)
async def clear(ctx, amount=1, limit_amount=1):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount+1)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=limit_amount)
    author = ctx.message.author
    await ctx.send(f'```Сэр, пропали сообщения, я не знаю сколько, может вы знаете?\n' + f'P.S Кол-во({amount})\n' f'P.S.S Удалил - {author}```')
````

Answer (score 0):

Надо вставлять названия или ID ролей вручную.

```
@commands.has_any_role(687992085416116235, 687622939985838080, ...)
```

Comment: Если нужно отдельными параметрами каждую роль передать, то достаточно добавить звездочку при передаче параметров: `@commands.has_role(*config.ADMIN_ROLES)`.